# PHP equivalent to jQuery html() or text()

Tags: php, jquery, html

Im trying to print the result of a php function to specific html id or class

the php function is called by a button input

jQuery code:

```
function myfunction() {
$answer = 'random text <b>' + $radomvar +'more random';
$('#resultline').html($answer);
}
```

is there an equivalent for the

```
$('#resultline').html($answer);
```

in php?

Comment: You might use `$('#resultline').text($answer);` but not the optimal one - `html` is best - `$('#resultline').html($answer);`

Comment: You might want to look into [PHP: DOMElement](http://www.php.net//manual/en/class.domelement.php) (and [PHP: DOMElement::getElementById](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.getelementbyid.php)).

Comment: Not in the way you want it to work I think.

Comment: should explain your use case if you want best possible solutions. Button event is in client and php runs on server

Answer (score 2):

What you're asking doesn't make sense. You can can embed PHP code alongside HTML code and it is processed by the server before the HTTP response is sent back to the client.

Therefore, why not do something like:

```
<span id="resultline"><?php echo myFunction(); ?></span>
```

Where `myFunction` is a PHP function that returns the string you want to embed?

Answer (score 2):

You can write your javascript code in .php file and then use your JavaScript function like this:

```
function myfunction() {
$answer = 'random text <b>' + '<?php echo myfunc($radomvar); ?>' +'more random';
$('#resultline').html($answer);
}
```

Comment: @Anonymous, are you talking about the above piece of code ?? just curious.. is writing js or html code in .php file not good ?

Comment: It's valid, as long as there's a ```?>``` closing tag before that section, which is assumed if OP is asking about a php parsed html or js file.

Comment: @pankaj I thought you meant that you wanted the function to be run as PHP code.  I clarified your answer.

Answer (score 0):

No there isn't. PHP is server side so after the request is done it can't change the webpage anymore. If you want to do that the only option is an AJAX call with for example JQuery as framework.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do proper DOM Manipulation with PHP. For the purpose of your question, you'd have to use jQuery's ajax function to request the variable value from the backend, and fill the container when you retrieve it.

js script:

```
jQuery.ajax({
    url: 'myfunction.php',
    data: {varname: randomvar},
    type: 'POST'
}).done(function(response) {
    $('#resultline').html(response);   
});
```

myfunction.php

```
<?php
function myfunction($radomvar) {
    $answer = 'random text <b>'. $radomvar .'more random';
    return $answer;
}

echo myfunction($_POST['varname']);
```

Please note that you don't need PHP to interpolate variables in a string. That function doesn't need PHP whatsoever to run. If the only purpose of PHP here is to get `$radomvar` value, and you're positively sure you want to have PHP in your frontend, then it would suffice to do something like

```
<script>
    function myfunction(radomvar) {
        var answer = 'random text <b>' + radomvar +'more random';
        $('#resultline').html(answer);
    }
    var randomvalue='<?php echo $radomvar; ?>';
    myfunction(randomvalue);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well their is no function equal to that in php, however you can easily achive the same effect rather easy by writing few more lines of code.

```
<div id="resultline"><?php  echo $answer; ?></div>
```

instead you have to place php echo code where you want printed out on the html page, otherweise you have to use ajax or something else than php.